# How to prevent Nginx from capturing errors from FastCGI/PHP-FPM?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I'm using Nginx 1.8.1 as a reverse proxy in front of PHP 5.6.20 over FastCGI (PHP-FPM), and I'm finding that all the notice/warning/error logs from PHP are also being logged in Nginx as errors. Is there any way to prevent such logs from propagating to Nginx' logs? I want them logged in PHP's log file only.

Here's an example:

> [29-Apr-2016 22:23:10] WARNING: [pool www] child 20 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /opt/web-app/index.php on line 2"

That same log is them added to Nginx' log file as an error:

> 2016/04/29 22:23:10 [error] 6#0: 1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /opt/web-app/index.php on line 2" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.2:9000", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/index.php"

Is there any change that I can make to my very simple configuration files for [Nginx](https://github.com/gnarea/docker-alpine-php-fpm/blob/0379fb6c1badd81c3bca3c39ed2de20d1c42c70e/nginx.conf) or [PHP-FPM](https://github.com/gnarea/docker-alpine-php-fpm/blob/0379fb6c1badd81c3bca3c39ed2de20d1c42c70e/php-fpm.conf)?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am on nginx and I have custom messages that I pass through the php error_log method. But when it gets to the nginx log it has the FastCGI sent in stderr at the beginning of some logs even though the custom message is a DEBUG type. If you've figured it out would really appreciate your input. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've been looking at the same issue, and after some trial and error, what worked for me is adding the below into the php-fpm pool configuration. I assume that the same flag could be set in other ways, such as the main `php.ini` file.

```
php_admin_flag[fastcgi.logging] = off
```

The relevant documentation is here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.fastcgi.logging

Comment: to expand a little bit, `catch_workers_output` will take stderr from all child processes and redirect it to php-fpm error log, and you probably want that to be `yes` or error output will just be discarded. `fastcgi.logging` on the other hand only affects whether it is sent back to the web server, but continues to output to the php-fpm error log (it could be `/dev/stderr`, which is separate to `fcgi_stderr`!)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `catch_workers_output` to `no` should do the trick:

```
catch_workers_output = no
```

This will let php log messages as configured but prevent those messages to be passed through the fastcgi connection to nginx.

Comment: Unfortunately, that just suppresses all the logs from the workers. They won't even be put in the PHP error file.

Comment: Try changing the value of the error_log directive (make is a file, say _/var/log/php-fpm.www.log_), with the original value for `catch_workers_output`.

Comment: `error_log` was already set and working properly. I wrote the comment above after testing `catch_workers_output` with both `yes` and `no`. Here's my config file, btw: https://github.com/gnarea/docker-alpine-php-fpm/blob/0379fb6c1badd81c3bca3c39ed2de20d1c42c70e/php-fpm.conf

Comment: I've found setting `catch_workers_output` to `no` suppresses logs from FPM, but they still appear in the nginx logs, where the opposite effect is desired (logs from FPM visible, nginx fastcgi logs suppressed